# Duda sobre pasar variables desde jquery a php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy intentando pasar varias variables sacadas de un calendario desde jquery en cuanto se clickea sobre una fecha determinada del calendario.
Cuand se clickea arroja la fecha a un input con id="my_hidden_input"

```
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
        $('#my_hidden_input').val(
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
        );
        var fecha = $('#my_hidden_input').val();
        console.log(fecha);
        var dia_fecha = fecha.slice(0,2);
        console.log(dia_fecha);
        var mes_fecha = fecha.slice(3,5);
        console.log(mes_fecha);
        var anyo_fecha = fecha.slice(6,10);
        console.log(anyo_fecha);
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function (){
            },
            url: "horarios.php" ,
            type: "post",
            data: {dia_f:dia_fecha, mes_f:mes_fecha, anyo_f: anyo_fecha},
            sucess: function (resp){
                console.log(resp)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, estado, error){
                console.log(estado);
                console.log(error);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, estado){
                console.log(estado);
            },
            timeout: 10000
        });


    });
```

Luego, para obtener la variable en el archivo horarios.php:

```
$dia_fech = $_POST['dia_f'];
```

> Me arroja el siguiente error: Notice: Undefined index: dia_f in
>   /home/u743999068/public_html/abm/horarios.php on line 68

En consola me sale lo siguiente:

20/07/2018
20 
07 
2018 
success

Código PHP:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="calendario/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="calendario/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="calendario/css/less/datepicker.less" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="calendario/css/build/build.less" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Mi horario</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#miMenu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="../login-register/index2.php" class="navbar-brand">Bienvenido usuario
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    echo $_SESSION['usr_name'];
                    ?>
                </a>
            </div>      
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="miMenu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="edit_form2.php">Perfil</a></li> 
                    <li class="active"><a href="horarios.php">Horarios</a></li> 

                    <li><a href="../login-register/logout.php"><span class="label label-danger">CERRAR SESION </span></a></li>                              
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">HORARIO</div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>HORAS</th>                          
                    <th>ACCION</th>             
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                     require('conexion.php');
                     $user=$_SESSION['usr_name'];
                     $result=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id_cita FROM citas where nombre_cita='$user'");
                     $cita=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                     $codcita=$cita['id_cita'];
                     if ($codcita==0){
                        ?>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div id="datepicker" ></div>
                                <input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
                            </div>
                        <?php
                         $dia_fech = $_POST['dia_f'];
                         $result=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM horarios where dia='$dia_fech'");
                         while ($horarios=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                             $id=$horarios['id'];                        
                             if ($horarios['Cliente']==null){
                         /*echo "<tr><td id='id:$id' class='cam_editable'>".$horarios['id']."</td>";*/
                         echo "<td id='horas:$id' class='cam_editable'>".$horarios['horas']."</td>";                                            
                         echo"<td id='$id' name='$user' button='true'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> Apartar</button></td>";
                         echo"</tr>";
                             }
                         }
                     }else{
                         $result=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM horarios where Cliente='$user'");
                         while ($horarios=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                             $id=$horarios['id'];
                             /*echo "<tr><td id='id:$id' class='cam_editable'>".$horarios['id']."</td>";*/
                             echo "<td id='horas:$id' class='cam_editable'>".$horarios['horas']."</td>";

                             echo"<td id='$id' name='$user' button='false'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Cancelar Cita</button></td>";
                             echo"</tr>";
                         }
                     }
                ?>
            </tbody>    

        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/maincita.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="calendario/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="calendario/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/calendario.js"></script>

</body>
```

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: y los name de ajax no van con comillas?, así
 `data: {'dia_f' :dia_fecha, 'mes_f': mes_fecha, 'anyo_f' : anyo_fecha},`

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez debería funcionar sin las comillas, de hecho tengo código así. El problema puede ser esto: `beforeSend: function (){
            },` quítale esa parte del `beforeSend` y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: @JuanLuisMirasMoreno define el `dataType: "text"` como otro de los parámetros del ajax para definir el tipo de contenido que mandas.

Si puedes poner el PHP para verlo, talvez sea ahí la cuestión

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código PHP completo. Gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);`  en tu archivo PHP? También cambia `type` por `method` aquí: `method: "post", `, pues `type` es para versiones antiguas de jQuery.

Comment: Respondiendo a @A.Cedano, muestra "array(0) { } "

Comment: O sea que no está posteando nada absolutamente... el POST está vacío. Revisa mi respuesta. Si no tienes jQuery 3 en esa parte del programa, conviene que lo actualices. Y verifica que `horarios.php` es exactamente tu archivo, no sea que el archivo que estés revisando sea otro, en otra carpeta, con el nombre `horarios.php`.

Comment: @A.Cedano el PHP tengo jquery 2.3, pero si actualizo al 3, bootstrap no me funciona. La ruta del archivo horarios.php está bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juan Luis, prueba a poner tu petición Ajax así:

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "horarios.php",
        data: {
            dia_f: dia_fecha,
            mes_f: mes_fecha,
            anyo_f: anyo_fecha
        },
        method: "post",
        timeout: 10000 
    });

    request.done(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, estado, error) {
        /*Aquí manejas el timeout*/
        if(estado=='timeout'){
            console.log('Ocurrió timeout... hacer lo que requieras');
        }else{
            console.log('Otro tipo de error ocurrió: '+ estado + " " + error);
        }
    });

    request.always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    });
```

Es probable que el `timeout` te esté dando problemas.

También, `success, error, complete` son obsoletos desde jQuery 3, por eso los he cambiado por `done, fail, always` ([ver las notas aquí](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). Los mismo ocurre con `type`, es para versiones antiguas de jQuery, deberías usar `method`.

---

#### Problema de comprensión sobre el funcionamiento de Ajax

Voy a tratar de explicar aquí brevemente cómo funcionan las peticiones Ajax, dado que veo un grave problema de comprensión en ese sentido y en comentarios es complicado explicarlo.

Lo primero que hay que tener claro ante las peticiones Ajax es que **hay dos lados: el lado del *cliente*  y el lado del *servidor***.

- **En el lado del *cliente***:

  - tendrás un DOM completo (HTML/PHP/Javascript), con todas las librerías que requieras, con formularios u otros elementos **para recoger**  los datos que el cliente (a través de acciones del usuario) enviará al servidor. Esos datos son los que envías en el parámetro `data` de la petición Ajax.
  - tendrás también, eventualmente, un contenedor, un `div` por ejemplo, que actualizarás de forma dinámica mostrando información traída del servidor o mostrando mensajes en base a lo ocurrido en el servidor. Ese contenedor se actualizará desde el bloque `done` de la petición Ajax.

---

- **En el lado del *servidor***:

  - tendrás un archivo que se ejecute en el servidor (por ejemplo `horarios.php` en tu caso) que se encargará únicamente de recibir la información que envías desde el cliente, la procesará y te devolverá información en base a lo que haya ocurrido.
  - ese archivo **no puede** ser un DOM completo (HTML/PHP/Javascript), tener librerías, bootstrap, etc, etc, etc. **Ese archivo es sólo un archivo utilitario** para recibir información desde el cliente, procesar esa información y devolver el resultado en un formato lo más simple posible para que el cliente lo procese de vuelta, mostrando su contenido en un contenedor suyo por ejemplo.

---

La estructura es la siguiente, explicada de forma simple.

1. **En el *cliente***:

Tendrás un archivo con todos sus componentes y librerías. Como este, presentado de forma muy básica. Es en este archivo donde está la petición Ajax:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Archivo del cliente</title>
    
        <!-- Librerías aquí como jQuery, Bootstrap, etc -->
    
        <script>
                /*
                   *... aquí todas las variables que requieras
                   *... y que has tomado de los elementos del DOM  
                   *Y luego, tu petición Ajax
                */

                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "horarios.php",
                    data: {
                        dia_f: dia_fecha,
                        mes_f: mes_fecha,
                        anyo_f: anyo_fecha
                    },
                    method: "post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 10000 
                });
        
                request.done(function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    /*
                        *Aquí se muestra en el contenedor info lo que trajo el servidor
                        *Dependiendo de cómo venga la información...
                        *si por ejemplo es solamente un mensaje de información
                        *harías simplemente esto:*
                    */
                    $("#info").html(resp);
                    
                    /*
                        *Si el servidor trae algo más, por ejemplo un JSON con 
                        *una o varias filas de datos
                        *entonces tendrías que parsear ese JSON, 
                        *construir una tabla con él y mostrarla
                        *o bien llenar los elementos de un formulario
                        *con los datos del JSON, etc, etce
                    */                
        
                });
            
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, estado, error) {
                    /*Aquí manejas el timeout*/
                    if(estado=='timeout'){
                        console.log('Ocurrió timeout... hacer lo que requieras');
                        $("#info").html('Ocurrió timeout... hacer lo que requieras');
                    }else{
                        console.log('Otro tipo de error ocurrió: '+ estado + " " + error);
                        $("#info").html('Otro tipo de error ocurrió: '+ estado + " " + error);
                    }
                });
        
                request.always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                });
        </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>    
        <!-- Aquí elementos para recoger datos, como formularios, datepicker o lo que sea -->
    
        <div id="info">
            <!-- MUY IMPORTANTE -->
            <!-- Este es el contenedor que se usará para mostrar las actualizaciones traídas desde el servidor mediante Ajax -->
            
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

2. **En el *servidor***:

Tendrás un archivo que sólo será un intermediario. Nada de librerías en él, nada de sacar por pantalla otra cosa que lo que el cliente ha pedido. Este archivo debe existir como un puente entre el cliente y el servidor, **para traer y llevar datos**. El encargado de formatear y presentar los datos es el otro archivo, el que envío la petición.

Es decir, que tu archivo `horarios.php` tendría una estructura como esta, más o menos:

```
<?php

    $laFecha=(empty($_POST["dia_f"])) ? NULL : $_POST["dia_f"] ;
    $arrResultado=array();
    if ($laFecha){
        
        /*
            *Lanzar por ejemplo una consulta a la base de datos 
            *usando como criterio $laFecha, 
            *recoger los datos, meterlos en un arreglo
            *y devolverlos
        */
        $datosObtenidos=array("cliente"=>"Pedro", "balance"=>5000); //Este es un resultado imaginario
        $arrResultado=$datosObtenidos;
        
    }else{
        
        $arrResultado["error"]="La fecha no fue enviada en el POST";    
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode($arrResultado);

?>
```

Lo **ÚNICO**  que ese archivo saca por pantalla es el dato que haya en `$arrResultado` en forma de un JSON. Ese dato puede ser lo que se haya traído de la base de datos, o un mensaje de error cualquiera.

Si la consulta es exitosa, tú tendrás ese JSON en la variable `resp` del `done` de la petición Ajax, deberás entonces *parsear*  esa información y presentarla como quieras en el contendor `info` del cliente. No importa lo que necesites presentar: una tabla, un formulario, un calendario, un libro completo ... lo que sea, lo que haga falta. Eso debes devolverlo desde el servidor en un formato adecuado y manejarlo en el `done`.

El archivo PHP sería entonces algo así:

```
<?php

    $laFecha=(empty($_POST["dia_f"])) ? NULL : $_POST["dia_f"] ;
    $arrResultado=array();
    if ($laFecha){
        
        /*
            *Lanzar por ejemplo una consulta a la base de datos 
            *usando como criterio $laFecha, 
            *recoger los datos, meterlos en un arreglo
            *y devolverlos
        */
        $datosObtenidos=array("cliente"=>"Pedro", "balance"=>5000); //Este es un resultado imaginario
        $arrResultado=$datosObtenidos;
        
    }else{
        
        $arrResultado["error"]="La fecha no fue enviada en el POST";    
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode($arrResultado);

?>
```

Simplemente, yo uso un operador ternario para verificar si en el POST, hay un elemento llamado `dia_f` (este es un ejemplo muy básico, no significa que tenga que ser así exactamente). Si `dia_f` fue posteado entonces lanzo por ejemplo una consulta a la base de datos y pongo los resultados de esa consulta en el array de resultado.  Si por el contrario, no fue posteado `dia_f`, en vez de resultados de la base de datos, pongo un mensaje de error en el array.

Y al final imprimo como un JSON lo que haya ocurrido.

Si has entendido esto, comprenderás que las peticiones Ajax son más simples de lo que puede parecer. Pero si no entiendes esto, no podrás tirar de todas las ventajas que ofrece Ajax.

Espero que ahora me hayas entendido mejor. Si tienes dudas, puedes preguntar en comentarios.

Comment: Me salta un "illegal character" en la linea 34 (que seria el ultimo });​ del código que has compartido).

Comment: Quité ; y ya funciona tu codigo. Pero sigue sin llevarme la variable correctamente.
Me da un success en consola, pero me arroja parte del código de horarios.php

Comment: Me suelta todo esto por consola:
http://collabedit.com/p87xe

Comment: Es probable que tengas que hacer ajustes en `horarios.php`. Si quieres prueba primero simplificando: comenta todo el código en `horarios.php` y pon solamente un código donde recibas la variable del POST y haces `echo` de ella. Si funciona entonces debes revisar todo el código PHP y devolver lo que vayas a usar y que recibirás en el `done`de Ajax.

Comment: O crea un archivo PHP muy simple y úsalo en la `url` de la petición Ajax.  Allí solo pruebas si recibe bien los datos. No se por que tienes tanto código ¿*basura*? en `horarios.php`... Los archivos que se pasan en la URL de Ajax suelen ser archivos intermediarios que reciben/devuelven datos. No se suele usar archivos HTML completos . Ese archivo no debe ser más que un intermediario y suele devolver un JSON que luego lees en el `done` y lo muestras en el archivo desde el cual se envió la petición Ajax. No sé si me entiendes lo que quiero decir.

Comment: Efectivamente, hice un archivo horarios2.php donde llevar la variable dia_f y mostrarle mediante un echo y muestra el valor correctamente. Hay algo en el archivo horarios.php que me impide que funcione.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu segundo comentario.
En el archivo horarios.php, además del menú, tengo un calendario, en el que el cliente debe pinchar una fecha del calendario.
Comprobar en la base de datos las fechas disponibles para realizar una reserva. Por eso mezclo html y php en el mismo.

Comment: Eso que dices en tu último comentario es muy raro. ¿Por qué tienes ese calendario en `horarios.php` y no en el archivo desde el que se envía la petición Ajax ? `horarios.php` como ya expliqué antes, es un intermediario, no tiene ningún sentido que muestre algo como un calendario. Ese archivo lo único que debería hacer es recibir la fecha o lo que le pases en el `data` de Ajax y consultar usando ese criterio. Creo que   en tu caso hay un error de comprensión sobre cómo funciona Ajax y para qué sirve realmente.

Comment: En horarios.php quiero que suceda lo siguiente: Si el usuario pidió con anterioridad una cita, se muestra esa cita con la opción de poder cancelarla. Si no tiene todavía una cita, se muestra el calendario. Puede pinchar en él y es entonces cuando se realiza la petición AJAX para obtener la fecha del calendario. Así, consulto en la base de datos si en esa fecha quedan citas disponibles. Las variables las quiero para poder realizar un SELECT en la base de datos. No sé si me expliqué bien al querer resumir toda mi idea.

Comment: Entiendo más o menos lo que quieres decir. Pero **no puedes hacer eso en horarios.php, eso tienes que hacerlo en el archivo que lanza la petición Ajax**. horarios.php no puede ser una página completa, con todos los elementos de una página, con scripts,  con librerías, etc, etc, etc. Para eso **ya tienes la página desde donde has lanzado la petición Ajax**. En esa página tú puedes tener un contenedor (un div por ejemplo) con un `id` y actualizarlo desde el `done`, mostrando un calendario o cualquier otro dato basado en la consulta realizada en horarios.php el es solo 1 puente no un DOM completo

Comment: Y podria crear un archivo llamado horarios2.php, donde obtengo las variables mediante AJAX (y funciona), y desde este archivo, pasar las variables a horarios.php?
Es decir, hay forma de pasar variables de un archivo php a otro php?

Comment: En referencia a tu último comentario, horarios.php es donde se lanza el archivo js llamado calendario.js, y pretendo que vuelvan los datos al mismo horario.php. Entiendo que esto no se puede hacer.

Comment: @JuanLuisMirasMoreno he explicado ampliamente el asunto en una nueva edición de la respuesta, en el encabezado **Problema de comprensión sobre el funcionamiento de Ajax**. Espero que así puedas entender mejor la cuestión.

Comment: Gracias, voy a leerlo con detenimiento y le digo.

Comment: No consigo comprender todo lo que me has escrito, ya que estoy empezando y estoy muy verde aún.
Planteé todo de una manera diferente.
Creé un archivo calendario.php, que es donde está el datepicker y ejecuta el archivo calendario.js, donde está el ajax.

Ahora, quiero mostrar, ya que tendria el dia,mes y año extraido del calendario por medio de ajax, una tabla con las citas disponibles para esa fecha en concreto.
Envio el ajax a un php limpio(horarios3.php), y luego reenvio las variables a un php más complejo(horarios1.php)?
Pensé tomar mediante session las variables de horarios3.php

Comment: Solucionado. Como dije en mi último mensaje.
Me gustaria saber como poder explicar mi solución para si alguien entra en este post y poder ver como se solucionó tod.