# Enviar información a otra pagina según el clic dentro dentro de un div

Tags: ajax, php7

Hola amigos tengo una duda con un proyecto nuevo que deseo implementar espero poder explicarme con claridad para que puedan entender lo que busco.

tengo un archivo `go.php` que contiene:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    @$id = isset($_POST['tr']) ? $_POST['tr'] : '';

    if(!isset($_POST['tr'])){
    $url = "http://google.com/";
    header('Location:'.$url.'');
    }else{
?>
<script>
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
</script>
<?php
    $idurl = $id;
    echo $idurl;
    }

    ?>
    <a class="myButton" href="ladin.php" target="_blank">HAZ CLIC AQUÍ</a>
```

el otro archivo `ladin.php` contiene :

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $(document).on('click','div', function(){ 
  datos();
 });
});


function datos() {

var parametros = {"tr":01};
$.ajax({
    data:parametros,
    url:'go.php',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    success: function (response) {   

    }
});
}
</script>

<div class="public">

</div>
```

lo que funciona que a la hora de dar un clic dentro del div con `class="public"` envía por ajax  un parámetro a `go.php` lo que yo busco es que con la pagina de go.php abierta al recibir ese parámetro se active una funtion o en este caso un simple `alert();` ahora la explicacion final

el la pagina `go.php` esta un enlace que abre en otra pagina `ladin.php` al dar clic sobre el div en `ladin.php` se manda un parámetro a `go.php` que debería de generar alguna reacción en la pagina ya abierta en este caso `go.php`. pero no pasa nada.

Comment: Intentar hacer eso es no entender Ajax ni para que sirve. En Ajax tu archivo `go.php` es una especie de mensajero, una pasarela para mandar los datos al servidor, que este los procese y te devuelva una respuesta. Quien debe actualizarse en tiempo real es el archivo desde el cual se manda la petición Ajax, no `go.php`. Si tú quieres actualizar `go.php` de forma dinámica tienes que hacer lo mismo allí, implementar código Ajax y usar en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax otro archivo PHP que haga de pasarela. No sé si me explico. Tienes Ajax mal enfocado y ese es el principal problema.

Comment: de seguro ese es el problema que no logro acomodar bien la configuración . según te entiendo necesito tener un tercer archivo que sirva de pasarela tanto para go.php como para ladin.php . el problema que miro es que necesito que ese tercer archivo logre activar en tiempo real la pagina de 'go.php' que ya esta abierta . no que abra otra . me explico . y gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Es que no entiendo ese punto: *el problema que miro es que necesito que ese tercer archivo logre activar en tiempo real la pagina de 'go.php' que ya esta abierta* Aparte de usar bien Ajax, creo que quizá tampoco tienes bien relacionados tus páginas. ¿Es que `go.php` es una página dependiente de otra? ¿Por qué? Lo suyo es que `go.php` mande su propia petición Ajax y sea actualizada con la respuesta que reciba del servidor. No entiendo por qué `go.php` necesite *ser activada desde otra página* ¿?

Comment: es para capturar el clic que ocurre en la pagina ladin.php . mas que todo mi curiosidad es saber si es posible mandar datos de una pagina a otra sin tener que abrir una nueva. aunque no sea por Ajax.

Comment: Es posible mandar datos de una página a otra, pero lo que tú quieres es mandar esos datos como en background y que esos datos se reflejen en la otra página sin recargarse ¿cierto? Eso no se puede hacer sin Ajax. Si por algún motivo **justificable** `ladin.php` y `go.php` tienen que estar separadas, entonces podrías mandar los datos desde `ladin.php` a algo así como una base de datos y en `go.php` tener un timer que lance una petición Ajax para buscar esos datos y mostrarlos, o crear una especie de listener que escuche las actualizaciones de la BD y te actualice `go.php`. Son ideas solamente.

Comment: me gusta tu idea sobre todo lo del timer seria algo de mantener go.php en espera ahora como me aconsejas un bucle o algo parecido en javaescript

Comment: No, un bucle no. Javascript tiene opciones de timer, sería cuestión de poner la petición Ajax dentro del timer. Y lo que haría esa petición sería buscar los eventuales datos nuevos en el servidor y mostrarlos en la página sin que esta tenga que recargarse. La petición Ajax se lanzará de acuerdo a los intervarlos de tiempo que indiques en el timer (cada una hora, cada minuto, cada segundo, cada 3 horas...).

Comment: De hecho, Ajax admite un parámetro `timeout` que sirve para indicar cada cuanto tiempo debe ejecutarse la petición. [Aquí hay un ejemplo explicando con suficiente claridad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/177672/29967). En esa respuesta se aborda también un poco cómo funciona Ajax, la comunicación entre cliente/servidor, que no era clara al principio al plantear tu pregunta.

Comment: disculpa usando Ajax dentro de go.php puedo verificar si existe un archivo en el servidor

Comment: Claro, desde Ajax puedes mandar a pedir cualquier información al servidor y recibir la respuesta de este, incluyendo saber si un archivo existe en determinado directorio.

Comment: perfecto me pongo a trabajar y si es posible publico la respuesta gracias